# Refreshing MVIEW is throwing a "table or view does not exist"

Tags: plsql, materialized-views

```
exec dbms_mview.refresh( 'TEST_MVIEW', method=>'C',atomic_refresh=>false)

Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2821
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3058
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3017
ORA-06512: at line 1
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The select query that is used for creating the MVIEW is working fine. Based on the answers from a thread, i have compiled the view as well. still the problem persists.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: is the access given via Oracle Roles?

Comment: i am not sure of that.

Comment: So when you compile the MVIEW it gets compiled successfully?

Comment: yes it is getting compiled successfully

Comment: Your view was imported from data pump ?

Comment: You are right  Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz . I selected all the objects that has staleness as IMPORT , dropped and recreated them.

Comment: I got the exact same issue now, did you find any solution for your problem?